# JavaScript | UnderscoreJS: Map Items in One Collection to Properties in Another

Tags: javascript, collections, mapping, underscore.js

#### Mapping An Item in One Collection to An Item's Property in Another Collection

I'm looking to use [any means, including] UnserscoreJS to map an object in one collection to a property of another object in a different collection. For example, map `[ { id: 998, ... }, ... ]` to `[ { thing: 998, ... }, ... ]`. In other words:

```
if (collection1[i].id === collection2[n].thing)
    collection2[n].thing = collection1[i];
```

Certainly, we can write this using a `map` function + an iterator for the second collection -- but my question is:

Is there a way to leverage another [say] UnderscoreJS efficacy to accomplish this efficiently and elegantly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Resolution

Use Underscore's `findWhere` method to pull the appropriate item from your collection using the Id you get from your mapping function:

```
var collection1 = [
    { id: 997, type: 'thing' },
    { id: 998, type: 'thing' },
    { id: 999, type: 'thing' },
    { id: 1000, type: 'thing' }
];
var collection2 = [
    { id: 111, type: 'otherThing', thing: 1000 },
    { id: 222, type: 'otherThing', thing: 999 },
    { id: 333, type: 'otherThing', thing: 998 },
    { id: 444, type: 'otherThing', thing: 997 }
];

_.map(collection2, function(otherThing){
    var thingId = otherThing.thing
      , thing = _.findWhere(collection1, { id: thingId });
    if (thing && thingId === thing.id) { otherThing.thing = thing; }
    return otherThing;
});
```

This is exactly what I was looking for, and I hope it helps save you some time as sometimes it can be like finding a needle in a haystack looking through large libraries' documentation.

Happy coding

Comment: You should use _.each as you're not really mapping (result of map is not assigned to anything). The `thingId === thing.id` is redundant in the if statement. Also thing will be set to the object in collection1 and not the id.